# Error message after backing up windows drive

Tags: 14.04

I was backing up a windows partition when the backup drive suddenly unmounted. Now whenever I try to mount the drive I get an error message:

[image: http://imgur.com/zzZ8dP8]

Answer (score 1):

Try starting up into windows, let it check the disks (it most likely will do this automatically). Then one windows has started do a proper shutdown, no quick boots or partial shutdowns. Then start back up into ubuntu and try again.

Thanks, hope this helps.

Comment: Well, it shows up on the windows machine but I cannot open the folder containing the backup, but that's an issue for another place.